# Cannot open Store of Office add-ins

Tags: microsoft-office

For a while, I could not enter the Store of Office add-ins from my Excel for Windows. It returns the error "Cannot reach this page" as follows.

The internet works, the version of my Excel is as follows.

Does anyone what is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Checked https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/microsoftstore.com.html ?

Comment: it is up... "Microsoftstore.com is UP and reachable by us."